# Single word for something that receives a request or response

Tags: synonyms

Something that sends `Requests`, can be called `Requester`, but is there a single word to denote a `Handler` / `Receiver`?

```
      Request Sender  > Request  > Request Receiver
AKA   Requester                    ? (Single Word Exists?)

      Response Sender > Response > Response Receiver
AKA   Responder                    ? (Single Word Exists?)
```

Is there any single word for the Request/Response Receiver?

`Request Sender` = `Requester`, `Response Receiver` = ? *(if there even is one)*

Comment: A single word to denote _handler_ is _handler_. I don't understand what else you need. Also, please note that naming classes is [specifically off topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: The agentive nominalization of _respond_ is _responder_; _response_ is an event nominalization of _respond_ that changes the stem from a final /d/ to a final /s/. This kind of stem change is very common in derivational morphology, especially when borrowed from Latin. But you have to start with the verb root, not one of the derived stems.

Comment: Request Sender = Requester, Response Receiver = ? (if there even is one)

Comment: @terdon, is there a single word to denote a `Response` `Handler`/`Receiver`? Its less about naming classes but more about English language. It just happened to come up while I was naming classes.

Comment: The response receiver is the requestor, no? The Requester requests. The Responder responds to the request.  And why would you want synonyms? To confuse other programmers?

Comment: Is Responder and Requestor not the same?

Comment: A Responder responds to a Request made by a Requestor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response

Comment: Sender > request > sendee (or addressee)            Responder > response > Respondee      http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/respondee

Comment: *Receiver* or *delegate*.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock thanks, I think this is the only viable solution.

Comment: @IanMacDonald But I need to distinguish between the type of receiver. E.g. Request Receiver / Response Receiver. I think Requestee and Respondee is probably the only solution?

Comment: @TRomano what if you have both in the same context? You need 4 descriptive nouns, to identify each separately.

Comment: @Michal Ciechan: I hope your code is clearer than your questions. "What if you have both in the same context?"

Comment: @TRomano I hope it is clean enoguh :-P http://codeperf.net/rx-request-response-throttle/

Comment: The one who receives something would be the *recipient*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing identifiers for computer programming is off-topic according to our Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sender > Request > Sender (or addressee)

Responder > Response > Respondee (*One who is responded to*)

http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/respondee

Answer (score 0):

A delegate, is what we call them is some programming environments.